# Nvidia 3D to 3D display

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, projector, 3d

I recently purchased an Epson 3020 projector which has 3D capability.
I connected my desktop computer using HDMI directly to the projector and my desktop has a Nvidia GTX 680 graphics card.

I have not used the 3D feature before and was trying to set it up for the first time.
I go into the nvidia control panel and enable the stereoscopic 3D, using the 3D setup wizard.
The display gets a little fuzzy but it won't let me adjust the 3D depth in the control panel afterwards.  I set the resolution to 1920x1080 and 24 HZ refresh rate like the wizard told me to at the end.

My projector is set on auto 3D, which I think automatically turns the 3D feature on the projector on when it detects a 3D source.

Just to be clear, the output from my desktop has to be 3D, and the projector has to be in 3D mode as well right?

I tried playing batman arkham city but I couldn't tell if it was 3D.
The desktop and some videos I played did not display in 3D.

I was wondering if there was something I had to do.
I adjusted the 3D depth on the projector, but even then, some of the videos and the game were not in 3D like I expected.

Am I not doing something correctly?

Comment: Don't know the full solution, but one thing to check is that the NVidia software correctly detects the projector as a 3D display.

Comment: @MBraedley - Good catch. I can check the nvidia control panel displays page, but will/should it say 3D display next to the display?

Comment: I'm not sure, not at my home machine at the moment.  I believe there is some indication somewhere in the control panel that a connected display supports stereo 3D.

Comment: @MBraedley - Cool, Thanks for the info. I am also not at my home machine but I will check when I get home.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is protected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some playing around and contacting support at NVidia, the representative said that the 3D technology of the projector is not supported by the NVidia 3D vision software/drivers.

So, if you are planning on using 3D, do not buy this projector if you are going to connect it to your Nvidia graphics card
OR
Don't buy a Nvidia graphics card if you have this projector.

Hopefully, this will help others having this problem.